# date mysql function error

Tags: mysql, function

i tried to use these mysql function for persian date
i got this error but i couldnt solve it

```
SQL query:

CREATE FUNCTION `persian_day` (
indate date
) RETURNS int( 11 ) BEGIN declare j int;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

i use mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev with phpmyadmin (xampp package)

here is my function

```
CREATE FUNCTION `persian_mod`(a double,b double) RETURNS int(11)
return (a - b * floor(a / b))

CREATE FUNCTION `persian_div`(a double,b double) RETURNS int(11)
return (floor(a / b))

CREATE FUNCTION `persian_pj`(y int,m int,d int) RETURNS int(11)
return ( 227260 +
        1029983 * persian_div((y - 474), 2820) + 
        365 * ( (persian_mod((y - 474), 2820) + 474) - 1) + 
        persian_div(682 * (persian_mod((y - 474), 2820) + 474) - 110, 2816) + 
        if(m > 6, 30 * m + 6, 31 * m)  
        + d )


CREATE FUNCTION `persian_day`(indate date) RETURNS int(11)
begin
declare j int;
declare a int;
declare b int ;
declare c int;
declare d int;
declare yearr int;
declare f double;
declare monthh int;
    set j=TO_DAYS(indate) ;
        set a = j - persian_pj(475, 0, 1) ;
        set b = persian_div(a, 1029983) ;
        set c = persian_mod(a, 1029983) ;
        set d = if(c <> 1029982, persian_div(2816 * c + 1031337, 1028522), 2820) ;
    set yearr = 474 + 2820 * b + d;
        set f = (1 + j) - persian_pj(yearr, 0, 1);
        set monthh= if(f > 186, ceil((f - 6) / 30) - 1, ceil(f / 31) - 1);

        return (j - (persian_pj(yearr, monthh, 1) - 1));
end
```

why this error happen?and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic syntax when creating a function is that you should have a return statement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnctionName (paramList)
RETURNS datatype
BEGIN
   RETURN valueToReturn;
END
```

but if you have special calculation (*of course it's multiline*) inside your function, you need to change the delimiter first:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION fnctionName (paramList)
RETURNS datatype
BEGIN
   DECLARE ....;

   ..... other codes ;

   RETURN valueToReturn;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

back in your case,

```
CREATE FUNCTION `persian_day` (indate date) RETURNS int( 11 ) 
BEGIN 
     declare j int;
```

you have not `RETURN` value and you haven't close the function using `END` keyword. Just like what you did on the other functions you have created.

**[CREATE FUNCTION Example](http://www.roseindia.net/mysql/mysql5/stored-procedures-and-functions.shtml)**

Comment: but i had return and end in that function as i put in question.